# How to move my cursor to the left in in my ComboBox?

Tags: wpf, text, combobox, cursor

I would like to move my cursor to the start of the text in my `ComboBox`.

This is what it looks like at the moment:

[image]

I did try the following on the `Closed Event`:

```
cboSomeCombo.Select(cboSomeCombo.Text.Length, 0);
```

The cursor still stays all the way to the right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be related:

[How to set the selected text of combobox align left](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/E86484FB-D7BE-4E04-8E66-0D12326817C8)