# How can I show the user what they are typing into an IsEditable ComboBox?

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox

When a user types into an IsEditable ComboBox, the items are automatically searched, the closest match is displayed, and as the user types, closer matches may be selected.  This works great.

Unless the string representation of the item is longer than the combobox is wide.  Then we have a problem.  As I understand it, when a too-long match is selected by typing, the underlying TextBox cursor is set to the right, which "right aligns" the item, which potentially hides where the user is actually typing.  In this example gif, typing "ABC" is fine, because it fits.  Typing "PQR" selects the right item, but the user can't see what they're typing: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OzZci.gif

The problem is described in this StackOverflow question:
[How to move my cursor to the left in in my ComboBox?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5456976)

And answered in this MSDN thread:
http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-us/wpf/thread/E86484FB-D7BE-4E04-8E66-0D12326817C8

The answer there is to hook the DropDownClosed event, find the TextBox in the ComboBox's visual tree, and set the TextBox's SelectionStart and SelectionLength.  However, this only works when picking an item from the dropdown portion of the combobox with the mouse.

Comment: this doesn't work with a selectionChanged event?

Comment: @Icepickle no, that seems to reset the cursor to the front (left) of the textbox after each keypress, and doesn't initiate any item matching.